# iPhone上の特定の位置を認識して自動でコピーする機能が欲しいです

Tags: javascript, ios, プログラミング言語

iPhone上の特定の位置(毎回識別する位置は変わらない)の場所を認識してコピーしてくれるコードが欲しいです。図2の様にショートカットアプリに埋め込んで使いたいです。
起動はショートカットにしてassistivetouchから行う予定です。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 1枚目は LINE の画面に見えますが、 iOS のショートカットで「他のアプリ上の文字列を取得」する機能があるのでしょうか？(ブラウザ上の文字列を取得とは恐らく勝手が違うと思われる) これができないと実現は難しそうです。

Comment: Webを分析するツールとかならあるんですけど他のアプリ上の文字を分析するツールとか無いですよね(ｰｰ;)

Answer (score 0):

> iPhone上の特定の位置を認識して自動でコピーする機能が欲しいです

現状で調べたところ、そのような機能はiOSで提供されていないようです。

スクリーンショットから文字を検出するなどは技術的に可能かもしれませんが、ショートカットから行うのは難しそうです。

機能の要望であれば、Appleのサポートに投稿してください。